# JQuery retrieving index on hasClass

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get the index on the first instance of a hasClass?

For Example:

```
$(".class").children().hasClass('classname').index();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: `hasClass` return a boolean, not a jQuery object.  What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.hasClass` returns a boolean, you can filter the results of `.children` to those that have the `classname`-class and then get the index:

```
$(".class").children(".classname").index();
```

Comment: Perfect! I don't know why I didn't think of it this way earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) returns a boolean, not a jQuery object; use a selector in [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead:

`$(".class").children(".classname").index()`.